# Metamask custom rpc not sending correct contract info

Tags: truffle, metamask, ganache

I have ganache running on localhost:7545 and I'm migrating deployments to ganache using truffle migrate with truffle-config.js port set to 7545. Then I am connecting to web3 in two ways:

```
web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:7545")
```

and

```
web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
```

The first case is working and the functions of my truffle deployments on 7545 can be called from web3js and they return the correct values.
However, in the second case, when I have Web3.givenProvider with custom rpc on metamask set to localhost:7545, even though the truffle deployments (set in 2_deploy_contracts.js) should return the correct values, they aren't.

They are set as follows in 2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var Creation = artifacts.require("./Creation.sol");                        
                                                                                  
                                                                       
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {                          
  deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-0", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1626763429000);                                          
  deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-1", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1658533626000);                                             deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-2", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1658533626000);                                      
  deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-3", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1658533626000);                                      
  deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-4", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1658533626000);                                      
  deployer.deploy(Creation, accounts[0], "creation-5", "creator-0", 100000000000000, "1000000000000000000", 1658533626000);                                      
                                                                              
  if (network == "live") {                                                        
    // specific actions to network named "live".                              
  }                                                                           
  console.log("Deploying Contract on Network: ", network);                    
  //                                                                          
  console.log("Deploying Contract on using Accounts: ", accounts);            
};
```

But the values that are set in the constructor aren't the values that I'm seeing when I'm calling the public variables that are set using the constructor (in the Web3.givenProvider case. All is working with "http://localhost:7545")
How to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to use `Web3.givenProvider`? If you are trying to connect Truffle with Metamask that won't be possible since Truffle runs on the command line and Metamask is a browser plugin. You could use in Truffle the same seed phrase than metamas with [HDWallet provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider).

Comment: I want to test my contracts in the browser using metamask

Comment: To connect a webpage to metamask follow the documentation provided in their site, for example https://docs.metamask.io/guide/create-dapp.html#project-setup.